# Illegal memory access in ARM

Tags: windows-phone-8, arm

I m facing a weird crash in one of my ARM targets [x86]. 
Windbg crash points an illegal memory access.

DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (d1)

An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an 
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.

Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000, memory referenced

Arg2: 00000002, IRQL

Arg3: 00000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation

Arg4: 8849fe99, address which referenced memory

This clearly tells me that i'm trying to access memory 0x00000000 at instruction 0x8849fe99. 
Dis-assembly of 0x8849fe99 code gives :

```
8849fe98 8818     ldrh        r0,[r3]
```

Register dump show :

```
r0=00000000  r1=8458ac70  r2=00000000  r3=00000000  r4=00000000  r5=00000000  
r6=00000000  r7=00000000  r8=00000000  r9=00000000 r10=00000000 r11=8458ac20 
r12=b7edbed9  sp=8458ac18  lr=8849fe8b  pc=8849fe98 psr=400000b3 -Z--- Thumb

8849fe98 8818     ldrh        r0,[r3]                             00000000=????
```

So, i was trying to access contents of memory at R3 - But R3 is 0x0000000 -Totally logical.

But here comes the fun part..
I try to check the code around the memory and find the following dis-assembly.

```
8849fe94 4620     mov         r0,r4

8849fe96 e8bd8818 pop         {r3,r4,r11,pc}

8849fe9a 0000     movs        r0,r0

8849fe9c 0000     movs        r0,r0

8849fe9e 0000     movs        r0,r0
```

- From the above code i notice that code at 0x8849FE96 is 32 bit instruction and is supposed to be executed at one shot.
- But debugger shows that it tried execute a 16-bit instruction (at 0x8849FE98)  - which is not expected at all !!
- Clearly, i have a 32-bit instruction which does the valid operation but why is my ARM thinking it as 16-bit instruction and splits my total sane instruction [e8bd8818 ] into 2 halves and executes a 16 bit instruction[8818] ?
- The code is being executed in THUMB Mode - meaning the processor should know when it is supposed to executed instruction in 16 bit mode and when in 32 bit mode.

Why is the processor thinking the instruction as 16 bit?

Comment: I would assume that you will get illegal instruction error before memory access violation error, if a 32bit instruction was executed as THUMB. Are you sure not accessing pageable memory when you are not supposed to?

Comment: @Ash Thumb here is Thumb-2 mode - which is mix of 16 / 32 bit instruction mode. So legally i can access either 16/32 bit instruction.But the problem i feel here is ARM is thinking the present instruction as 16 bit instead of a 32 bit - which puzzles me.

Answer (score 0):

If the processor is in THUMB mode, it will execute THUMB code.
**It does this by reading 16-bit instructions, always.**
If the instruction read is a "prefix" to a 32-bit THUMB instruction, like `blx`, then it will read the next 16-bit instruction to complete it.

But in your case, the lower half of `E8BD8818` is `8818`, which is `ldrh r0, [r3, #0x0]` and not a composite 32-bit instruction, so it will execute that.

`E8BD8818` is **not** a valid THUMB instruction.
It is however a valid ARM instruction, `ldmia sp!, {r3,r4,r11,pc}`, it being an equivalent to `pop` in THUMB – but you cannot pop the "high" registers, r8 to r14, as there just isn't enough bits in the pop instruction's bit pattern to encode that in THUMB.